# How format a time in hours greater than 24 hours AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, time-format

I have a decimal value in minutes with the value **3361** and need to convert in hours and present in this format: **56:01:00**

I tried this code:

```
$scope.myTime = new Date(1970, 0, 1).setMinutes(3361);

<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'">
```

But the result is not that I expected: **08:01:00**

Comment: You can use MomentJS for this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: your regular date ain't gonna work because the OP wants hours > 24.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I need a hint to use the time> 24

Comment: @JonB have an example of this?

Comment: There are only 24 hours in a day. `56:01:00` is not *time* at all. It's an amount of hours, minutes and seconds delimited with colon. Converting it to `08:01:00` *time* is the expected behaviour. If you don't need it to be *time*, parse and process it by hand, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fear that you can't acheive what you need using angular `date` filter.

You can create you custom filter (here [angular official guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)) and build the result in the format you need.

For example, you can create a [moment duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) using `moment.duration(3361, 'minutes');` and then use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) to get the duration in the `HH:mm:ss` format.

Here a full live example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.filter('durationFormat', function() {
  return function(input) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = '';
    var dur = moment.duration(input, 'minutes');
    return dur.format('HH:mm:ss');
  };
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myTime = 3361;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  {{ myTime | durationFormat }}
</div>
```

---

Another way to get the same output is using [angular-moment-duration-format](https://github.com/vin-car/angular-moment-duration-format) that has filters to use and display moment duration. You can create your duration using [`amdCreate`](https://github.com/vin-car/angular-moment-duration-format#amdcreate-filter) specifying `'minutes'` unit and then format it using [`amdFormat`](https://github.com/vin-car/angular-moment-duration-format#amdformat-filter).

Here an example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['angularDurationFormat'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myTime = 3361;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vin-car/angular-moment-duration-format/0.1.0/angular-moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  {{ myTime | amdCreate:'minutes' | amdFormat:'HH:mm:ss' }}
</div>
```

PS. I'm the creator of [angular-moment-duration-format](https://github.com/vin-car/angular-moment-duration-format).

Comment: hi, how do I make sure,that the time is always displayed in HH:mm:ss format? right now, after adding your changes, its showing ss for time in seconds(instead of 00:00:ss), for minutes it shows mm:ss (instead of 00:mm:ss)and so on

Comment: i looked into the moment js library and figured it out , just had to pass the settings obj arg with trim:false like - amdFormat:'HH:mm:ss':0:{trim:false} and it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in AngularJS date/time filters that will accomplish what you're trying to display.

You can however create a [custom AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) which will achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`% 60` will give you minutes spared. Then you can simply subtract and divide it by 60 to get number of hours.

```js
function minutesToHours(min) {
   var minutes = min % 60;
   var hours = (min-minutes)/60;
   minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
   return hours+':'+minutes+':00';
}

console.log(minutesToHours(3361));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your scope with below also add $filter in your controller

```
$scope.myTime = $filter('date')(new Date(1970, 0, 1).setMinutes(3361), 'HH:mm:ss');
```