# Formatting MomentJS duration above 24 hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to format a summed up total working hours e.g. **49.75** to this: **49:45**.

When I use duration like this:

```
const dur = moment.duration(49.75, 'hours').asMilliseconds();
moment.utc(dur).format("HH:mm:ss") // 01:45:00
```

I'll receive **01:45:00** instead of **49:45:00**

Is there a way to format (instead of **HH**) duration without dropping the days?

Comment: As you see in the example I'm using moment.duration so far. What's missing is an appropriate formatting function for that or at least a momentJS plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42985372/5349795).

You can add a format for the duration, and it works for greater than 24 Hour.

```
function(input) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = '';
    var dur = moment.duration(input, 'minutes');
    return dur.format('HH:mm:ss');
};
```

I hope it can help you!

**EDIT:**

This code uses [duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plugin!

Comment: For moment.duration() there is no format function. So the code above doesn't work at all.

Comment: Its just a piece of code, do you check the whole answer what I linked?

Comment: The code above depends on a plugin from [jsmreese](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) and didn't work on it's own. It would be great to highlight this in your answer.

Comment: you are right! I edited my answer, i don't want to mislead anybody. :)

Answer (score 16):

I think you cannot use format but build it manually:

```
var dur = moment.duration(49.75, 'hours');
var hours = Math.floor(dur.asHours());
var mins  = Math.floor(dur.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
var sec   = Math.floor(dur.asSeconds()) - hours * 60 * 60 - mins * 60;

var result = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + ((sec > 9) ? sec : ("0"+sec));
console.log(result); // 49:45:00
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w97ghzam/)</kbd>

---

<sup>Hope someone will find more elegant way</sup>

Comment: Your solution here is what I have so far. I thought there is a formatting function build into momentJS or at least a momentJS plugin for that.

Comment: Nice hack! I like it more than using the duration format plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying one second at a time, it can be simplified quite a lot (parsing and updating).

Inspiration lifted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629433/11121690

```
incrementTime: (sectionKey, itemKey) => {
    const pad = (number) => `${number > 9 ? number : "0" + number}`;
    const timeString = STATS_DATA_UTIL.getByParts(sectionKey, itemKey);
    const parts = timeString.split(':');
    let uiSecs = parseInt(parts[2]);
    let uiMins = parseInt(parts[1]);
    let uiHrs = parseInt(parts[0]);

    uiSecs++;
    if (uiSecs === 60) {
        uiSecs = 0; uiMins++;
        if (uiMins === 60) uiMins = 0; uiHrs++;
    }

    const result = `${pad(uiHrs)}:${pad(uiMins)}:${pad(uiSecs)}`;
    STATS_DATA_UTIL.setByParts(sectionKey, itemKey, result);
},
```